# Inject only SOME controllers from a seperate assembly into REST

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, controller

I have some controllers in a seperate assembly that I want to include. I am able to add all of them just find using AddApplicationPart(). But I only want some of them to be added. I am trying to make a controller provider that overrides IsController but the change isn't being applied:

This is my ConfigureServicesMethod:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        foreach (Assembly assembly in ServiceSettings.AssembliesWithControllers)
        {
            services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(assembly)
                .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
            {
                manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new ControllerProvider(Configuration));
            }).AddControllersAsServices();
        }

        services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck("MainHealthCheck", new HealthCheck(), HealthStatus.Unhealthy);
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc(ServiceSettings.Version, new OpenApiInfo { Title = ServiceSettings.ServiceName, Version = ServiceSettings.Version });
        });
    }
```

And this is my ControllerProvider (for testing purposes I am just returning false right now, but I am still seeing all of my controllers):

```
public class ControllerProvider : ControllerFeatureProvider
{
    public readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ControllerProvider(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override bool IsController(TypeInfo typeInfo)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this method is not working to exclude controllers or have a better suggestion for how to exclude some controllers?

Edit: Update:

This will work, but I lose the ability to add multiple assemblies nd I would like to be able to find a way to marry the two solutions.

```
services.AddControllers(options => options.Filters.Add(new BaseActionFilter()))
            .AddApplicationPart(ServiceSettings.AssembliesWithControllers[0])
                .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
                {
                    manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new ControllerProvider(Configuration));
                });
```

Comment: Why are you concerned about it?

Comment: Well it doesn't work. my understanding of the code above is that none of my controlled should be added. All of them are,

Comment: I meant "why do you care that they're all added?" or "what are you trying to achieve by preventing some being added?"

Comment: Ah. Well I have a lower package that runs a rest connection on a different port. It gets the calling assembly injected to it and will get all of those controllers that way. I also have a rest connection running on the calling app. I want some controllers added on connection A, some on connection B. How it is now, all of my controlllers are active on both connections. I can use an action filter to return 404 for the ones that I choose, but I think a controller provider would be a lot cleaner